# Swiftui Scrollview text change color onTapGesture

Tags: uiscrollview, swiftui

I want change color of the Text item onTapGesture for simulate the selected item, when click the Text color should be Red and other Text Black.

```
           ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(newsFeed.subcategoryListNews) { item in
                        Text(item.name)
                            .font(Font.custom("AvenirNextLTPro-Demi", size: 17))
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                //Chage color and reset other Text, active red not active black
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 30)
                .padding(.horizontal, 30)

            }.padding(.bottom, 10)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to conform your item type `Equatable` (if it is not yet) then the following approach is possible

```swift
@State private var selectedItem: <Item_Type_Here>? = nil

...

ForEach(newsFeed.subcategoryListNews) { item in
    Text(item.name)
        .font(Font.custom("AvenirNextLTPro-Demi", size: 17))
        .foregroundColor(self.selectedItem == item ? Color.red : Color.black))
        .onTapGesture {
            self.selectedItem = item
        }
}
```